# Angular 2.2.0 component-relative path (SystemJS) module is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I trying Component-relative Template URLS as this

dialog.component.ts

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'modal-confirm',
    templateUrl: 'dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls:  ['dialog.component.css']
})
```

tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
     ....
  },
```

systemjs.config.js

```
typescriptOptions: {
  emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
  experimentalDecorators: true,
  module: "commonjs",
},
```

Using JiT, I got

```
Error: (SystemJS) module is not defined
ReferenceError: module is not defined at eval (http://localhost:3000/app/shared/services/dialog.component.ts!transpiled:104:35)
```

Click on the link and it goes t this line

```
moduleId: module.id,
```

What have I missed?

**UPDATE**
I actually received more errors than above mentioned. There are a number of cases where AoT requires stricter code to pass the type-checker. It is much more complicated than I would expect. What works in JiT mode may not work in AoT mode. I would wait for another 3-6 month to see how AoT compiler improves.

Comment: Are you using dist folder or something???

Comment: yes, I am using dist folder. Does that has any impact on relative path error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you are using *dist* folder, make sure you copy all your required files eg `.css, .js` to dist folder same as default directory structre (same directory structure as you have before running your **gulp/grunt** task

Comment: I copied the html and css to the dist folder in their corresponding structure. But still the same error. If I change url back to absolute path it works fine. Is it the relative path + moduleId not working with JiT?

Comment: Few threads are available for the same in github. please check for it. They  might resolve your problem. Its all about right configuration. If you are using webpack or system.js, configuration will differ.